# url for django updating user profile

Tags: django

So far I have done some research, most of the solutions seems outdated. I have extended my user profile using the following codes below. The updating form is rendered but when I summit the form, I get an error. Bellow is my code, please help sort out the mistakes I did.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
     picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_image", null=True, blank=True)
     company = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
         UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

views.py

```
def  update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
         create_account_form = Create_account(request.POST, 
         instance=request)
         profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, 
         instance=request.user.userprofile)
         if create_account_form.isvalid() and profile_form.is_valid()
           create_account.save()
           profile_form.save()
           return redirect('app_namespace:url_name')
         else :
            messages.error(request, 'fill out the form correctly')
     else:
        create_account_form = Create_account(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
     return render(request, "app_name/editprofile.html",{'user_form':creat_account_form,'profile_form':profile_form})
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns =[
        url(r'Update_profil/$', views.update_profile, name="profile_update")

     ]
```

Url for profile_acount where the user is redirected when the form is summitted

```
  url(r'profileAccount/$',views.profileAccount.as_view(),name='profile_account')
```

html

View for  profileAccount

```
class profileAccount(generic.ListView):
model = UserProfile
template_name ='success/user_account/profile_account.html'




<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ user_form.as_p }} {{ profile_form.as_p }} <button type="submit">Save changes</button>

</form>
```

Error

when I summit form, I get the error  below. I know the error has to do with the url and view, I have done lots of research, most are outed. please help me out with the most accurate working example of updating my userprofile thanks very much .

ERROR

Reverse for 'profile_accounts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
 It returned None instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some changes in your view,

```
def update_profile(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        create_account_form = Create_account(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if create_account_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            create_account.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('app_namespace:url_name')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'fill out the form correctly')
    else:
        create_account_form = Create_account()
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    return render(request, "app_name/editprofile.html", dict(user_form=create_account_form, profile_form=profile_form)
```

- return statement should be outside`if`/`else` clause.
- form must be passed into context.

NOTE: I have said these based on what you posted, not what you have in your editor.

**EDIT**

Add a '^' at beginning of the regex, the symbol represents starting of the pattern. Omitting the "^" caused the NoReverse Match error.

```
url(r'^profileAccount/$',views.profileAccount.as_view(),name='profile_account')
```

Comment: About the return statement i did .But it shows same error .Do i need to pass the user object from my view ,and what about about my urls.py ,i think is incorrect as well

Comment: What does your create form do, why are you passing request to it... Remove it like I did in my answer.. and try

Comment: create_account_form gets authenticated user information and display them in the form  to be  edited/updated.I tried what you requested but same error .

Comment: You sure that your form valid is True??

Comment: How can i implement form validation=True in view.py .I am new to django .Please help with full explanation or with code examples as you did above.Thanks

Comment: Post your both forms then

Comment: Please have a look at my url .I am pretty sure the error i am getting has something to with it .NoReverseMatch at /Update_profil/
Reverse for 'profile_accounts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: This 'profile_accounts' view?? Could you show this view?? Is this in the redirect function??

Comment: Same problem bro .If you had worked with such a project before .please share your code .I may be my work is deprecated and there is an easy way to go through this

Comment: Did you add "^" in the url like '^profileAccount/$'

Comment: Yes added .I did all the modifications you suggested .But same errorNoReverseMatch at /Update_profil/
Reverse for 'profile_accounts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Change the name from 'profile_account' to 'profile_accounts' in your urls.py

Comment: How is it now looking

Comment: It now works  but can not view the changes made .How can i view changes or render the chances in to my html file .

Comment: Post your template and ask another question, one issue per question brother, if I can I'll answer it

Comment: Thanks ,I will !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the last line back one indent.

Comment: error :Reverse for 'profile_accounts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? And no, your indents are not correct, otherwise you wouldn't have got the original error.

Comment: So far my indents are correct  .If not ,I will have an error exception  from my local server ,And my app would not have been  able to run .But in this scenario my app runs very well   ,and  my user profile edit form renders  with no problem as well .But when i summit the form , an error occurs  .I  am pretty sure it has to do with the urls .py  and the view.py  lacking the user object .But i do not know how to go about solving it .

Comment: It is completely impossible to answer your question. What error are you talking about now, and why did you post the other one?

Comment: Reverse for 'profile_accounts' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
here is the error